# Form validation in yii

Tags: validation, yii

I trying to post form in yii but don't have any idea regarding validation, i go through some yii documentation but not getting it. can't we do validation without form object of yii? means in view i am using normal HTML for form of yii.

Comment: So you are not using Yii Form builder or nor yii form elements and still wants to use Yii validation ? Be more specific while you are asking for help.

Comment: yes, actually i am not using yii form builder. so question is that can't we use yii form validation without form builder

Comment: Sure we can. Can you go through actionContact() as example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation is built into Yii in Models, whether it is Form models or CActiveRecord models.

In order to implement validation, place the validation rules in your model. In the example below, I am using an activerecord model.

```
class Customer extends CActiveRecord {
//    :
public function rules(){
   return array(
      array('name, surname, email', 'required'),
      array('age, email', 'length','min'=>18)
   );
}
```

You can now validate ANY form, whether you are using Yii forms or plain HTML forms.

To enforce validation, your controller must populate the model values, then call upon the model to check the data against the rules you defined earlier.

```
    class CustomerController extends CController {
         //      :
        $customerModel = new Customer;
        // Set fields using this format ...
        $customerModel->attributes['name'] = $_FORM['user'];
        // ...or this ...
        $customerModel->age = $_FORM['age'];
        // ...of this 
        $customerModel->setEmail($_FORM['email'];

        // Now validate the model
        if ($customerModel->validate) {
           return true;
        }
        else {
           return false;
        }
        //    :
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In action, you need to add

```
$this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

in _form, add

```
'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
```

and in model, you need to set rules,

```
public function rules(){
return array(
    // array('username, email', 'required'), // Remove these fields from required!!
    array('email', 'email'),
    array('username, email', 'my_equired'), // do it below any validation of username and email field
);
}
```

I think, this will be helpful for you.

Comment: thank you, but in this we have to create form controller like <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::activeLabel($model,'emp_name'); ?>
        <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'emp_name') ?>
    </div>
But can i do same with simple HTML form?

Comment: yeah, you can add simple html.    Eg : <input class="form-control" name="Suppliers[first_name]" id="Suppliers_first_name" type="text" maxlength="50" value="Rogin">

Comment: thanks its working it display error with 
if($model->validate())
   {
    echo 'validation complete';
   }
   else
   {
    print_r($model->getErrors());
   
   }
how can i display that error on view?

Comment: Add <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?> in _form to show error.

Comment: EG:  <div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'first_name'); ?>
  <?php echo $form->textField($model,'first_name',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?>
 </div>